# Why was Gellert Grindelwald only extensively investigated for his alleged crimes against the Muggle community, but not the magical community?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, gellert-grindelwald, the-secrets-of-dumbledore

Why was Gellert Grindelwald only extensively investigated for his alleged crimes against the Muggle community, but not the magical community?

In *Secrets of Dumbledore*, in the winter of 1932, current Supreme Mugwump Anton Vogel absolves Gellert Grindelwald of all of his alleged crimes against the Muggle community but doesn't speak of his crimes in magical Europe, the magical United States of America, and magical France, where he impersonated, injured, and/or killed countless Aurors alongside his acolytes.

Is it a plothole that Gellert Grindelwald was not also extensively investigated for his crimes in the magical community? In 1926, he was already being chased by aurors from several magical governments, and he was nearly captured in a derelict chateau somewhere in Europe.

Comment: Perhaps Grindelwald didn't commit as many crimes against the magic folk as the muggles? Grindelwald seems to focus on muggles - "rule over them", "for the greater good" . . . etc. Whereas the only few magic folks he kills (that we know of, there may be more) are Leta Lestrange, Aurelius Dumbledore (Credence Barebone), the Aurors, carriage drivers and those dudes on those broomsticks that were at the wrong place at the wrong time.

Comment: @Silvermidnight "...the Aurors, carriage drivers and those dudes on those broomsticks that were at the wrong place at the wrong time." These aurors, drivers, and those dudes on those broomsticks were of the ICW Department of Aurors. No matter how few wizards and witches he killed, murder was still punishable by life in prison.

Comment: Which did happen to Grindelwald. My point is, wizarding world justice systems are kind of crazy. We see that this depends on who the leader is and what the outside circumstances are. Sort of like the Harry and Fudge incident. The moment Voldemort came back, the ministry started acting very nice.